# assigning value to a variable in angular component from a subscribe of observeble HTTP request

Tags: javascript, angular

when I want to assign a value to a local variable in Angular component from subscribing HTTP request
 I get undefined

```
  patient: Patient;
  hpId: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.fetchPatient(id);
    console.log(this.hpId);
  }
  fetchPatient(id: number) {
    this.patientService.getPatient(id)
    .subscribe( data => {
      this.patient = data;
      this.hpId = this.patient.appointment[0].healthProfessionalId;
    });
  }
}
```

I want to use the value of hpId out of the scope of subscribing method

Comment: The value of `hpId` is undefined when the component initializes. You have to put the console log inside the `fetchPatient` subscription.

Comment: @Ayaman Safi But that will be undefined until you get it from your HTTP call. It will give you undefined always as it will be executed before your HTTP call completes

Comment: Your code is all good, if you try to console inside `subscribe` you will see the value. The reason you are seeing it as undefined is because of asynchronous behavior.

Comment: Do you want to display that Id in HTML?

Comment: use the `| async` pipe if you are displaying it inside the template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

1) If you want to display `hdId` in HTML page then use like `{{ hpId }}`

2) If you want to call another API then you can wrap that call inside `.subscribe()` call like

```
fetchPatient(id: number) {
    this.patientService.getPatient(id)
    .subscribe( data => {
      this.patient = data;
      this.hpId = this.patient.appointment[0].healthProfessionalId;
      this.yourMethod(this.hdId); // here
    });
}

yourMethod(hdId){
     console.log(hdId);  // do whatever with `hdId`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Coding in typescript is like plumbing..you have to code like a
  stream. If you turn the tap on but if the water is on the way until it reaches the 
  tap there won't be water so if you planned to wash your clothes you have to do it 
  after the water comes from the tap.
- So when you call the method this.fetchPatient(id); it will hit the
  back-end and wait in the subscribe until it gets data or error.after
  the this.fetchPatient(id); then you put your  console.log(this.hpId);
  at this point data is not retrieved but the call was made therefore
  it will show undefined. if you want to see data put the console log
  inside subscribe after this line this.hpId =
  this.patient.appointment[0].healthProfessionalId;
- Furthermore if you want to use value of this.hpId in other methods
  call those methods after this.hpId =
  this.patient.appointment[0].healthProfessionalId; line.