# Angular : How to convert values in array and get value in outside scope?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

Here In`DynamicDatabase` class I fetch value from server and got In `console.log(this.rootLevelNodes) // folder-1 folder-2 folder-3 folder-4` see In below code but I want this value in array. and then outside `this.route` I print `console.log(this.rootLevelNodes) // there I got null [] (this.rootLevelNodes) in function but I dont know why I got null result` but there where also I want In array format result how it is possible see my below code and help me ?

```
@Injectable()
export class DynamicDatabase {

  rootLevelNodes: string[] = [];
  constructor(private route : ActivatedRoute, private userService : UserService){}
  upperFolderId;
  urlOfFolder;

  initialData(): DynamicFlatNode[] {

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {

      this.upperFolderId = params['userid'];
      this.urlOfFolder = params['url']+'/'+this.upperFolderId;

      this.userService.getPatternMainFolder({'urlOfFolder' : this.urlOfFolder}).subscribe(
        (data) => {
          if(data != undefined && data != '' && data.payload != undefined && data.payload != ''){
            for(var i = 0 ; i < data.payload.length ; i++){
              this.rootLevelNodes = data.payload[i].folderName;
              console.log(this.rootLevelNodes); // folder-1
                                                   folder-2
                                                   folder-3
                                                   folder-4
                                                   <-- this type result I got

              // I want this type result 
              console.log(this.rootLevelNodes); // ['folder-1','folder-2','folder-3','folder-4']
            }
          }
        }
      )
    });

    console.log(this.rootLevelNodes);  // [] --> Here I result got null array

     // Here also I want this type result want
    console.log(this.rootLevelNodes); //  ['folder-1','folder-2','folder-3','folder-4']
    return this.rootLevelNodes.map(name => new DynamicFlatNode(name, 0, true));
  }
```

Comment: that is async call!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I print console so outside console is first print but How to resolve this

Comment: What do you want to do with that variable? Wanna use in HTML or call api?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I want to use in HTML

Comment: Just like this? --> `{{rootLevelNodes | json }}`

Comment: Refer this answer-->https://stackoverflow.com/a/53904951/7124761

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I return this values see last lines of my code it sended to other component so i have to do here , and in last line I got null result so how to get values there

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49605090/how-to-return-value-inside-subscribe-angular-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split the single function into two parts:

```
initialData() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.upperFolderId = params['userid'];
      this.urlOfFolder = params['url']+'/'+this.upperFolderId;
      this.anotherFunction(this.urlOfFolder);
    });
  }

anotherFunction(data) {
    this.userService.getPatternMainFolder({'urlOfFolder' : data}).subscribe(
    (data) => {
     if(data != undefined && data != '' && data.payload != undefined && data.payload != ''){
    for(var i = 0 ; i < data.payload.length ; i++){
      this.rootLevelNodes.push(data.payload[i].folderName);
      console.log(this.rootLevelNodes);
    }
  }
  return this.rootLevelNodes;
  }
 )
}
```

Comment: I already trying return inside so it gives error like this [ts] A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.

Comment: Can you split the function into two?

Comment: Pashant as per parshwa answer I push and got array but now how to fetch array in second console where I got null array

Comment: still it gives error like this (A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value. in anotherFunction)

Comment: Replace `anotherFunction(data): DynamicFlatNode[]` with `anotherFunction(data):{}`

Comment: @PrashantPimple Thank you so much and upvote my question

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `this.rootLevelNodes = data.payload[i].folderName;` do `this.rootLevelNodes.push(data.payload[i].folderName);`

Comment: Thanks parshwa I got array but now how to get ouside scope this array that i got array null

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: Parshwa see my question's last two lines In that console I got array null but I want there where also array values

Comment: Parshwa I dont know how to create and use stackblitz

Comment: Try `this.rootLevelNodes: string[] = [];` in constructor and check